# 100% width align three images

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to get three images to fit in a 100% width div. Id like to have keep 5px margin between each image. any suggestions?

css:

```
#about_imagebar {
    width:100%;
    margin-top:5px;
}
#about_left {
   display:inline-block;
   float:left;
   margin-right:5px;
   width:25%;
}
#about_middle {
   display:block;
   margin:0 auto;
   width:50%;
}
#about_right {
   display:inline-block;
   float:right;
   margin-left:5px;
   width:25%;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="about_imagebar">
    <div id="about_left">
        <img src="images/about_banner_1.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div id="about_right">
        <img src="images/about_banner_3.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div id="about_middle">
        <img src="images/about_banner_2.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

thanks!

Comment: try padding:5px; it will keep 5px space in all about all #about_imagebar childs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your elements are set to `display: inline-block`.
Meaning they are treated as inline elements too. And inline elements takes white spaces between them.

So when you say 25% + 25% + 50% it may be 100% but there is that space that will make it 100% + 5-6px and they will not fit. The fix is simple add `font-size: 0` to the parent div (a.k.a `#about_imagebar`)

The other problem is your margin since you are using % width you should use % margin too.
So it should be `margin-right: 1%; width: 24%` for example or you can calculate it properly.

In code:

```
#about_imagebar {
    width:100%;
    margin-top:5px;
    font-size: 0;
}
#about_left {
   display:inline-block;
   float:left;
   margin-right:1%;
   width:24%;
}
#about_middle {
   display:block;
   margin:0 auto;
   width:50%;
}
#about_right {
   display:inline-block;
   float:right;
   margin-left:1%;
   width:24%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the quick answers! got it working now ;-D

Comment: @user2220758, no problem. Please accept answers that worked for you by clicking the check button on the left side of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
#about_imagebar {
    width:100%;
    margin-top:5px;
    padding:5px; /* or 0 5px if you don't need a top and bottom padding */
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
}
#about_left {
   display:inline-block;
   width:25%;
}
#about_middle {
   display:inline-block;
   margin:0 auto;
   width:50%;
}
#about_right {
   display:inline-block;
   width:25%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
#about_imagebar > div {
   display: inline;
   padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using margin-left and margin-right for the divs and by setting this you need to decrease the width than 100% in total because it adds spaces and increased width from 100% to plus margin values:

```
#about_imagebar {
    width:100%;
    margin-top:5px;
}
#about_left {
   display:inline-block;
   float:left;
   margin-right:5px;
   width:24%;
}
#about_middle {
   display:block;
   margin:0 auto;
   width:49%;
}
#about_right {
   display:inline-block;
   float:right;
   margin-left:5px;
   width:24%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So your problem is a poor undestanding of the [box model](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/). Margin is added to the width, so you end up with 100% + 10px, which obviously won't fit. One options is to use `calc` for your width but it does have [browser limitations](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc). Using [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) you can also streamline your HTML

HTML

```
<div id="about_imagebar">    
    <img src="images/about_banner_1.jpg" class="left" />   
    <img src="images/about_banner_3.jpg" class="middle" />    
    <img src="images/about_banner_2.jpg" class="right"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#about_imagebar {
    width:100%;
    margin-top:5px;
}

 #about_imagebar .left {       
   float:left;
   margin-right:5px;
   width:calc(25% - 5px);
}

#about_imagebar .middle {
   display:block;
   float:left;
   width:50%;
}

#about_imagebar .right {
   float:right;
   margin-left:5px;
   width:calc(25% - 5px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your markup and css accordingly

HTML

```
<div id="about_imagebar">
<div id="about_left">
<img src="images/about_banner_1.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="about_middle">
<img src="images/about_banner_2.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="about_right">
<img src="images/about_banner_3.jpg" />
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#about_imagebar { width:100%; margin-top:5px;}
#about_imagebar div {background:#ccc} /* I have used for just view the DIV, you can remove it */
#about_left { display:inline-block; width:calc(25% - 5px);}
#about_middle { display:inline-block; width:50%; }
#about_right { display:inline-block; width:calc(25% - 5px);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your css as given below:

```
#about_imagebar {
    width:100%;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-left:5px;
}
#about_left {
   display:inline-block;
   float:left;
   margin-right:5px;
   width:25%;


}
#about_middle {
   display:block;
   margin:0 auto;
   width:25%;
}
#about_right {
   display:inline-block;
   float:right;
   margin-left:5px;
   width:25%;
}
```

Hope it will work!